# VS Code build task: "cd" command not working

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

I am trying to create a build task to quickly deal with building the project. However, I am not able to `cd` into the project directory to execute the `makefile` containing the commands.

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "Build",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "cd /path/to/folder; make build",
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Error message:

```
The terminal process terminated with exit code: 1
```

Even just the `cd` command gives the same error. Running `pwd` instead shows that I am in root `/`.

Am I missing something. Couldn't find any help on web search.

Environment:
- Windows 10 
- I have WSL installed

**EDIT:**

Tried setting

```
    "options": {
        "cwd": "${fileDirname}/.."
    }
```

`fileDirname` was pointing to the `.vscode` folder inside my project folder, so thought `..` from it would work. But `pwd` still show it is in root.

Comment: Did you try reloading the windows ----- `Ctrl + Shift + P` and then type reload windows press enter.

Comment: Tried ```reload window```. No luck

Comment: Is this answer helpful: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171677/cd-into-all-directories-execute-command-on-files-in-that-directory-and-return

Comment: Nope, but thanks. The error pops up when using ```cd```.

Comment: Have you tried using "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/your-folder"?